# mapviz - missing multi-res-image and tile-map plugins

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use mapviz to plot the location of a robot on a geo-referenced map. The multi-res-image plugin for mapviz seems perfect for my application but when I click add the options are missing for multi-res-image and tile map.

I installed using apt-get like so `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-mapviz ros-indigo-mapviz-plugins`
I'm using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Should I try installing from source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245142/mapviz---missing-multi-res-image-and-tile-map-plugins/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Downloading from source works. You can follow the download instructions [here](https://github.com/swri-robotics/mapviz)

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even easier than installing from source, install these packages: `sudo apt-get installs ros-indigo-tile-map ros-indigo-multires-image`

PS, for Rviz + Offline Google Maps checkout my tutorial: https://github.com/danielsnider/MapViz-Tile-Map-Google-Maps-Satellite

---

Originally posted by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) with karma: 203 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-09-12**:
Hi
I have followed the step you mentioned. I can see the mapproxy via http://localhost:8080/demo/# url. But the map is not available in the mapviz and in terminal I can see an error
[/mapviz_saptarshi_hp_z620_workstation_12482_9148411003242316701/ImageCache::NetworkError:251]: NETWOR

**Comment by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on 2018-09-12**:
What is the error message that you see?

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-09-12**:
HI
I am sorry. It worked. It usually takes some time

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-09-12**:
[/mapviz_saptarshi_hp_z620_workstation_16751_8005112130639167216/ImageCache::NetworkError:251]: NETWORK ERROR

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-09-12**:
ImageCache::NetworkError:251]: NETWORK ERROR

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-09-12**:
Hi
When the fixed frame is "far_field" it works fine, but when the fixed frame is wgs84 it kinda stopped working with the same error as mentioned before "Network Error .......". I have no idea the reason behind this